# Using breadcrumb component inside lazy loaded modules injected by router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-routing

I'm building angular 8 breadcrumb component. Application requires it to be displayed usually in the content of the page (not only) but it's never located in the header which could be outside router-outlet. And this is where the problem appears. 
I'm using lazy loaded modules, placing  component inside lazy loaded component templates.

I wanted to create an observable. Map to router root firstChild by using filter first. But I can't manage to pass the condition... 
This is what I have tried so far.

```
breadcrumbs$: Observable<Breadcrumb[]>;

constructor(router: Router, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
this.breadcrumbs$ = router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
                map(() => {
                    return this.buildBreadcrumbs(activatedRoute.root.firstChild);
            })
        );
}

buildBreadcrumbs(route: ActivatedRoute) {
// logic
}
```

The problem appears only when breadcrumb component is rendered inside router-outlet. If I place it on the same level in the template then it works just fine.
Normal if condition checking for NavigationEnd event with subscription to router.events works. Is there any way arround?

Thanks for your suggestions!

**Edit:** I attached some real life example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/breadcrumbs-mwsp

Comment: your problem statement is little vague. can you create a stackblitz that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @ysf sure! Look at the example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem appears only when breadcrumb component is rendered inside router-outlet. If I place it on the same level in the template then it works just fine.

The component is being *destroyed* when the route changes, because it's inside the `<router-outlet>` it becomes part of the route content. When the route changes the component is destroyed and never receives the `NavigationEnd`. When the component is outside it lives longer and will receive the event.

You can easily fix the issue by giving your observable a *starting value*.

```js
    this.breadcrumbs$ = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      startWith(undefined),
      map(() => {
          return this.buildBreadcrumbs(this.activatedRoute.root.firstChild);
      })
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me, I just needed to start with my buildBreadcrumbs() method. I will mark it as proper answer.